# why i don't recive an updated object?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have the following custom hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { AuthType } from '../types';

export function useAuth() {
  const [ authData , setAuthData ] = useState<AuthType>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if ( authData && authData.JWT ) {
      localStorage.setItem( 'JWT', authData.JWT );
    }
  }, [ authData ]);

  return {
    authData,
    isAuth: authData !== undefined,
    setAuthData
  };
}
```

and I'm using it in my header:

```
export default function Header() {
  const { isAuth, authData } = useAuth();
  console.log(isAuth);
  return <div> {isAuth} </div>;
}
```

and I always get `false`, am I doing something wrong here?
in my login component I'm updating my authData using setAuthData:

```
const { setAuthData } = useAuth();

axios.post().then(({ data }) => {
  setAuthData({
    PWT: data.PWT,
    ...
  });
})
```

Comment: There's nothing calling `setAuthData`, so `authData` is always undefined.

Comment: I'm calling it in my login component, and setting a data! sorry i should say that

Comment: You are not updating the authData anywhere.

Comment: i updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instance of the hook has its own state.

When you use the hook in your Header component and your Login component, they do not **share** a state.

When you Login component calls `setAuthData` it only updates `authData` variable returned to the Login component. The other `authData` returned to the Header component is untouched.

You need some way to share the state between the hooks such as a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [redux store](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).

Comment: oh, right! ill try using the context and i'll reply to u, thanks.